# Add data into prolog with text

Tags: text, prolog

```
?-dynamic(setup/5).
setup :-
    seeing(S),
    see('people.txt'),
    read_data,
    write('data read'),
    nl,
    seen,
    see(S).
read_data :-
    read(A),
    process(A).
process(A) :- A == end_of_file.
process(A) :-
    A \== end_of_file,
    write('1'),
    read(B),
    read(C),
    read(D),
    read(E),
    assertz(person(A,B,C,D,E)),
    read_data.
```

and the text are

```
john.will.30.london.doctor.
martha.will.33.portsea.doctor.
henry.smith.26.manchester.doctor.
```

the result is coming out

```
?- setup.

* Syntax Error

* Syntax Error

* Syntax Error

* Syntax Error

* Syntax Error
data read
yes
```

What happens? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you precise the prolog implementation you use and give the whole error message + what you are intending to do ? Kinda unclear question at the moment

Comment: im adding the texts into the prolog's database. btw, it is a win-prolog. and it is the whole error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading with read/1 which expects valid Prolog text as input. However, your data is

```
john.will.30.london.doctor.
```

which is invalid. Write something like

```
person(john,will,30,london,doctor).
```

instead. Most often, people do not read  in such data manually. Instead, they load the file with `['datafile.pl']` or other commands.